# Javascript When Installing Tailwind CSS is not working

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I followed this tutorial https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/phoenix
Everything appears to work fine except for the javascript and the annoying phoenix banner.

Can anyone resolve my issue?

this is my current page

[image: current indexpage]

When I tap "solutions" nothing happens, which indicates that the javascript is not working.

these are my settings

mix.exs:

```
defmodule ?.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :?,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.12",
      elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env()),
      compilers: [:gettext] ++ Mix.compilers(),
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      aliases: aliases(),
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end

  # Configuration for the OTP application.
  #
  # Type `mix help compile.app` for more information.
  def application do
    [
      mod: {?.Application, []},
      extra_applications: [:logger, :runtime_tools]
    ]
  end

  # Specifies which paths to compile per environment.
  defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "test/support"]
  defp elixirc_paths(_), do: ["lib"]

  # Specifies your project dependencies.
  #
  # Type `mix help deps` for examples and options.
  defp deps do
    [
      {:phoenix, "~> 1.6.6"},
      {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 4.4"},
      {:ecto_sql, "~> 3.6"},
      {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
      {:phoenix_html, "~> 3.0"},
      {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.2", only: :dev},
      {:phoenix_live_view, "~> 0.17.5"},
      {:floki, ">= 0.30.0", only: :test},
      {:phoenix_live_dashboard, "~> 0.6"},
      {:esbuild, "~> 0.3", runtime: Mix.env() == :dev},
      {:swoosh, "~> 1.3"},
      {:telemetry_metrics, "~> 0.6"},
      {:telemetry_poller, "~> 1.0"},
      {:gettext, "~> 0.18"},
      {:jason, "~> 1.2"},
      {:plug_cowboy, "~> 2.5"},
      {:tailwind, "~> 0.1", runtime: Mix.env() == :dev}
    ]
  end

  # Aliases are shortcuts or tasks specific to the current project.
  # For example, to install project dependencies and perform other setup tasks, run:
  #
  #     $ mix setup
  #
  # See the documentation for `Mix` for more info on aliases.
  defp aliases do
    [
      setup: ["deps.get", "ecto.setup"],
      "ecto.setup": ["ecto.create", "ecto.migrate", "run priv/repo/seeds.exs"],
      "ecto.reset": ["ecto.drop", "ecto.setup"],
      test: ["ecto.create --quiet", "ecto.migrate --quiet", "test"],
      "assets.deploy": ["tailwind default --minify", "esbuild default --minify", "phx.digest"]
    ]
  end

end
```

config.exs:

```
# This file is responsible for configuring your application
# and its dependencies with the aid of the Config module.
#
# This configuration file is loaded before any dependency and
# is restricted to this project.

# General application configuration
import Config

config :?,
  ecto_repos: [?.Repo]

# Configures the endpoint
config :?, ?Web.Endpoint,
  url: [host: "localhost"],
  render_errors: [view: ?Web.ErrorView, accepts: ~w(html json), layout: false],
  pubsub_server: ?.PubSub,
  live_view: [signing_salt: "qKKXtXjI"]

# Configures the mailer
#
# By default it uses the "Local" adapter which stores the emails
# locally. You can see the emails in your browser, at "/dev/mailbox".
#
# For production it's recommended to configure a different adapter
# at the `config/runtime.exs`.
config :?, ?.Mailer, adapter: Swoosh.Adapters.Local

# Swoosh API client is needed for adapters other than SMTP.
config :swoosh, :api_client, false

# Configure esbuild (the version is required)
config :esbuild,
  version: "0.14.0",
  default: [
    args:
      ~w(js/app.js --bundle --target=es2017 --outdir=../priv/static/assets --external:/fonts/* --external:/images/*),
    cd: Path.expand("../assets", __DIR__),
    env: %{"NODE_PATH" => Path.expand("../deps", __DIR__)}
  ]

# Configures Elixir's Logger
config :logger, :console,
  format: "$time $metadata[$level] $message\n",
  metadata: [:request_id]

# Use Jason for JSON parsing in Phoenix
config :phoenix, :json_library, Jason

# Import environment specific config. This must remain at the bottom
# of this file so it overrides the configuration defined above.
import_config "#{config_env()}.exs"


# configure the Tailwind Version

config :tailwind, version: "3.1.4", default: [
  args: ~w(
    --config=tailwind.config.js
    --input=css/app.css
    --output=../priv/static/assets/app.css
  ),
  cd: Path.expand("../assets", __DIR__)
]
```

dev.exs:

```
import Config

# Configure your database
config :?, ?.Repo,
  username: "",
  [![passw][2]][2]ord: "",
  hostname: "",
  database: "",
  show_sensitive_data_on_connection_error: true,
  pool_size: 10

# For development, we disable any cache and enable
# debugging and code reloading.
#
# The watchers configuration can be used to run external
# watchers to your application. For example, we use it
# with esbuild to bundle .js and .css sources.
config :?, ?Web.Endpoint,
  # Binding to loopback ipv4 address prevents access from other machines.
  # Change to `ip: {0, 0, 0, 0}` to allow access from other machines.
  http: [ip: {127, 0, 0, 1}, port: 4000],
  check_origin: false,
  code_reloader: true,
  debug_errors: true,
  secret_key_base: "7zFMMjwz67h8pDGEwPpwjm2ToUu7WlJ4saC3B31sZKMahmnzk6SP0IXNwIeiF5id",
  watchers: [
    #
    tailwind: {Tailwind, :install_and_run, [:default, ~w(--watch)]},
    # Start the esbuild watcher by calling Esbuild.install_and_run(:default, args)
    esbuild: {Esbuild, :install_and_run, [:default, ~w(--sourcemap=inline --watch)]}
  ]

# ## SSL Support
#
# In order to use HTTPS in development, a self-signed
# certificate can be generated by running the following
# Mix task:
#
#     mix phx.gen.cert
#
# Note that this task requires Erlang/OTP 20 or later.
# Run `mix help phx.gen.cert` for more information.
#
# The `http:` config above can be replaced with:
#
#     https: [
#       port: 4001,
#       cipher_suite: :strong,
#       keyfile: "priv/cert/selfsigned_key.pem",
#       certfile: "priv/cert/selfsigned.pem"
#     ],
#
# If desired, both `http:` and `https:` keys can be
# configured to run both http and https servers on
# different ports.

# Watch static and templates for browser reloading.
config :?, ?Web.Endpoint,
  live_reload: [
    patterns: [
      ~r"priv/static/.*(js|css|png|jpeg|jpg|gif|svg)$",
      ~r"priv/gettext/.*(po)$",
      ~r"lib/?_web/(live|views)/.*(ex)$",
      ~r"lib/?_web/templates/.*(eex)$"
    ]
  ]

# Do not include metadata nor timestamps in development logs
config :logger, :console, format: "[$level] $message\n"

# Set a higher stacktrace during development. Avoid configuring such
# in production as building large stacktraces may be expensive.
config :phoenix, :stacktrace_depth, 20

# Initialize plugs at runtime for faster development compilation
config :phoenix, :plug_init_mode, :runtime
```

tailwind.config.js:

```
// See the Tailwind configuration guide for advanced usage
// https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './js/**/*.js',
    '../lib/*_web.ex',
    '../lib/*_web/**/*.*ex'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms')
  ]
}
```

assets/css/app.css:

```css
/*@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";*/

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

/* This file is for your main application CSS */

/* Alerts and form errors used by phx.new */
.alert {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.alert-info {
  color: #31708f;
  background-color: #d9edf7;
  border-color: #bce8f1;
}
.alert-warning {
  color: #8a6d3b;
  background-color: #fcf8e3;
  border-color: #faebcc;
}
.alert-danger {
  color: #a94442;
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #ebccd1;
}
.alert p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.alert:empty {
  display: none;
}
.invalid-feedback {
  color: #a94442;
  display: block;
  margin: -1rem 0 2rem;
}

/* LiveView specific classes for your customization */
.phx-no-feedback.invalid-feedback,
.phx-no-feedback .invalid-feedback {
  display: none;
}

.phx-click-loading {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}

.phx-loading{
  cursor: wait;
}

.phx-modal {
  opacity: 1!important;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.phx-modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15vh auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

.phx-modal-close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.phx-modal-close:hover,
.phx-modal-close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fade-in-scale {
  animation: 0.2s ease-in 0s normal forwards 1 fade-in-scale-keys;
}

.fade-out-scale {
  animation: 0.2s ease-out 0s normal forwards 1 fade-out-scale-keys;
}

.fade-in {
  animation: 0.2s ease-out 0s normal forwards 1 fade-in-keys;
}
.fade-out {
  animation: 0.2s ease-out 0s normal forwards 1 fade-out-keys;
}

@keyframes fade-in-scale-keys{
  0% { scale: 0.95; opacity: 0; }
  100% { scale: 1.0; opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fade-out-scale-keys{
  0% { scale: 1.0; opacity: 1; }
  100% { scale: 0.95; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes fade-in-keys{
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fade-out-keys{
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

assets/js/app.js:

```
// We import the CSS which is extracted to its own file by esbuild.
// Remove this line if you add a your own CSS build pipeline (e.g postcss).

// If you want to use Phoenix channels, run `mix help phx.gen.channel`
// to get started and then uncomment the line below.
// import "./user_socket.js"

// You can include dependencies in two ways.
//
// The simplest option is to put them in assets/vendor and
// import them using relative paths:
//
//     import "../vendor/some-package.js"
//
// Alternatively, you can `npm install some-package --prefix assets` and import
// them using a path starting with the package name:
//
//     import "some-package"
//

// Include phoenix_html to handle method=PUT/DELETE in forms and buttons.
import "phoenix_html"
import "../css/app.css"
// Establish Phoenix Socket and LiveView configuration.
import {Socket} from "phoenix"
import {LiveSocket} from "phoenix_live_view"
import topbar from "../vendor/topbar"

let csrfToken = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']").getAttribute("content")
let liveSocket = new LiveSocket("/live", Socket, {params: {_csrf_token: csrfToken}})

// Show progress bar on live navigation and form submits
topbar.config({barColors: {0: "#29d"}, shadowColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)"})
window.addEventListener("phx:page-loading-start", info => topbar.show())
window.addEventListener("phx:page-loading-stop", info => topbar.hide())

// connect if there are any LiveViews on the page
liveSocket.connect()

// expose liveSocket on window for web console debug logs and latency simulation:
// >> liveSocket.enableDebug()
// >> liveSocket.enableLatencySim(1000)  // enabled for duration of browser session
// >> liveSocket.disableLatencySim()
window.liveSocket = liveSocket
```

EDIT:

the JS is working i just forgot to do this

```
       <!--
          'Solutions' flyout menu, show/hide based on flyout menu state.

          Entering: "transition ease-out duration-200"
            From: "opacity-0 translate-y-1"
            To: "opacity-100 translate-y-0"
          Leaving: "transition ease-in duration-150"
            From: "opacity-100 translate-y-0"
            To: "opacity-0 translate-y-1"
        -->
```

I kinda know what to do now but what would be the best way?

Comment: I don't think the required javascript is included with the tailwind templates, you can inspect the live examples to see the javascript parts and implement them as you see  fit

Comment: Also have a look at Phoenix.Liveview.JS if you're using 0.17.0 or later, it added JS commands which make this even more trivial than alpinejs or solutions alike

Answer (score 2):

As this question seems to float around a lot here's a minimalistic implementation example (I would recommend adding something to your javascript sources instead of adding javascript to your templates);

```
<button onclick="toggle_visibility();">hamburger</button>

<script>
  function toggle_visibility() {
    var e = document.getElementById('mobile-menu');
  
    if(e.style.display == 'block') {
      e.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      e.style.display = 'block';
    }
    return;
  }
</script>
```

For live views (0.17 onwards) its actually easier just add the following to your button:

```
phx-click={JS.toggle(to: "#mobile-menu")}
```

Comment: I think i see what the problem is, js is working but i have to do this

Comment: <!--
              'Solutions' flyout menu, show/hide based on flyout menu state.

              Entering: "transition ease-out duration-200"
                From: "opacity-0 translate-y-1"
                To: "opacity-100 translate-y-0"
              Leaving: "transition ease-in duration-150"
                From: "opacity-100 translate-y-0"
                To: "opacity-0 translate-y-1"
            -->